# Changing data-percentage attribute based on function results?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got an issue that I've been trying to solve for a while now, and would greatly appreciate any help.

I've got a progress bar with the following attributes:

```
<div class="bar-cont" data-percentage="0">
```

If I change the data-percentage manually, between 0-100, then the progress bar works perfectly.

However, the percentage will vary depending on the user, so I was wondering whether it's possible to set the data-percentage to the result of the code below (which only produces a result after a button is clicked).

```
Math.floor(finalResult.result[0]* 100)
```

The above code does produce a value between 0-100 & is nested within a couple of functions.

I've tried various methods, such as querySelectorAll, getElementById, setAttribute etc. without success.

From my understanding, the data-percentage might not actually be an attribute at all, as it seems to be written as:

```
var percentage = $(bar).data('percentage') / 100;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following to set the value of a data attribute:

```
document.querySelector('.bar-cont').dataset.percentage = 50;
```

Or, with jQuery:

```
$('.bar-cont').data('bar-cont', 50);
```

Both of these will set the value of the data attribute to 50.

Comment: That works if I put it in the global scope, but not when it's nested (in a couple of functions & an if / else statement).

I'm wondering whether it's an issue with the progress bar not updating after the button is clicked?

Comment: @Jack This answer is in no way tied to a certain scope.

Comment: @Schlaus Oh right, thanks. Is it likely to be an issue with the progress bar not updating after the button is clicked and the results are returned? Because if I do something like `document.querySelector('.bar-cont').dataset.percentage = 50;`, as suggested above, then that does override `data-percentage` when I load the page. However, if I put that same code in a function, then it won't override it when the function is called.

Comment: @Jack Could be any number of things. You should post the relevant code in your question. As it is, it's not really possible to help more than this answer does.

Comment: What Schlaus said, we'll need to see the actual code :)

Comment: @Schlaus Good point, my bad. This is the original code used: http://codepen.io/kylephillips/pen/KwpvgP - which is all but the same now.

Comment: @Jack - I don't see any line that sets the value for the 'percentage' data attribute. I've forked your pen here where I've added it to your 'setGauge' function (1st line).

http://codepen.io/chrislo2401/pen/qRyPZo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
var percentage = $('.bar-cont').data('percentage') / 100;
... or any other calculation
$('.bar-cont').data("percentage", percentage);
```